# Error al ejecutar app desde consola de Windows: java.sql.SQLExecption: No suitable driver foun dor jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/

Tags: java, mysql, cmd, jdbc

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Hola amigos, estoy creando un programa para gestionar películas para una oferta de trabajo, uso el IDE de NetBeans y puedo ejecutar el código sin fallas, me conecta a la base de datos (estoy usando MySQL y JDBC) y puedo hacer consultas, updates y demás dentro del IDE. Pero en el CRUD que me pidieron, el programa tiene que ser ejecutado desde la consola de comandos de Windows y a pesar de que todo lo tengo bien estructurado y compila a la perfección, al momento de crear un archivo con el mismo código para ejecutarlo desde la consola, me da este error. ¿Alguien tiene alguna posible solución? Les agradecería.

Answer (score 2):

El IDE (Netbeans) te añade en el classpath las dependencias declaradas (en este caso el driver de MySQL) automáticamente al ejecutar, por tanto tienes que hacer lo mismo al escribir el comando:

```
$ java Peliculas -cp <ruta al fichero .jar>
```

Comprueba dónde está el fichero con el driver de MySQL y pon su ruta en el classpath (cp).

Comment: Sigo obteniendo el mismo error, incluso pasé el .jar para el escritorio donde está el archivo, puse el .jar como valor en el classpath de las variables de entorno y no hay resultado positivo.